# Mac OS X Guest Virtual Box in Windows Host Full Screen

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

Is there a way to make the Mac OS X guest OS adapt the resolution of the host OS given that there's no guest additions yet as of the moment?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for it to automatically adjust, but you can specify a custom resolution for the guest to use.

You can manually edit the VirtualBox configuration, and the boot file in OS X to use a custom resolution. It's a two part (Host VM/Guest) process to enable the resolution.

Here are the steps:

1. First, make sure VirtualBox is not running. Close it if it is.
2. Add the following setting to the `<ExtraData>` section of your VM's XML file (location `C:\users\<username>\VirtualBox VMs\<OS_NAME>\<OS_NAME>.vbox-prev`):

   `<ExtraDataItem name="CustomVideoMode1" value="1680x1050x32"/>`

   You can change the value above to your preferred display resolution, e.g. 1280x1024x32.
3. Save the file and start your VM.
4. In Mac open the `/Extra` folder in the Finder.
5. Drag the `com.app.Boot.plist` file to the desktop.
6. Open the file on the desktop in the editor.
7. Locate the `<key>Graphics Mode</key>` entry, following that there should be
   a `<string>xxxxxx</string>` entry.  Edit this entry to match the Custom Video entry
   from step 2 above. i.e. `<string>1680x1050x32</string>`
8. Put file back, Restart your VM and the new display resolution should be effective.

Good Luck!

Comment: This doesn't work. The only thing that seems to make a difference is using the solution described here: http://martinml.com/en/how-to-install-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-in-virtualbox/

Comment: This definitely doesn't work, the copy on the desktop is just ignored. See http://superuser.com/questions/478901/change-macos-x-guest-screen-resolution-for-virtualbox for a more up-to-date method.

Comment: @T.Todua: (1) Why do you suggest editing `<OS_NAME>.vbox-prev` instead of `<OS_NAME>.vbox`? (2) What do you mean by "Put file back"?

Answer (score 1):

That should help solving your problem.

- open [this](http://www.macbreaker.com/2012/07/mountain-lion-virtualbox.html) link
- go down to Step 7: *Make the Screen Bigger*

**Note**: Install [Multibeast 4.6.1](http://www.tonymacx86.com/downloads.php?do=cat&id=6) first (registration required)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but none of the other answers helped me. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MViezRuuF2I) helped me. The instructions are very simple:

1. Power off your VM
2. Close VirtualBox, and any background processes (if applicable).
3. In the following code, edit "VM Name" to be your VM name and "N" to be 0 for a screen resolution of 640 x 480, 1 for 800 x 600, 2 for 1024 x 768, 3 for 1280 x 1024, 4 for 1440 x 900, and 5 for 1900 x 1200:

   `cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox"`

   `VBoxManage setextradata "VM Name" VBoxInternal2/EfiGopMode N`
4. Run the code in command prompt as admin

That should get the job done. If anything is unclear, check out the linked video.