# Change MacOS X guest screen resolution for VirtualBox

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have tried all alternatives and resources that I found on internet to achieve to change screen resolution in my MacOS X guest. I have the latest VirtualBox version (4.1.22) and I have MacOS X 10.6.3 Snow Leopard running in a vm guest.

Some solutions that don't work for me are:

- Tuning virtual machine settings:

Adding  and  in the .vbox file, or running these two commands:

```
vboxmanage setextradata "MAC OS X" "CustomVideoMode1" "1360x768x32"
vboxmanage setextradata "MAC OS X" "GUI/CustomVideoMode1" "1360x768x32"
```

- Editing Guest OS boot configuration:

Modify /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.boot.plist with these lines:

```
<key>Kernel Flags</key>
<string>"Graphics Mode"="1360x768x32"</string>
<key>Graphics Mode</key>
<string>1360x768x32</string>
```

Any other suggestion, something that I was missing.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: have you installed the Guest Additions?

Comment: Until now, there are no Guest Additions for MacOS Guest.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am using VirtualBox under Ubuntu Linux, and a Mac OSX (Mountain Lion) as guest OS.

For me, the full resolution started working when I did all of the following:

0) Install MultiBeast 4, making sure that the system boots from the virtual hard disk rather than from any booting CD. I followed the instructions here:

http://www.macbreaker.com/2012/07/mountain-lion-virtualbox.html

However, at the end of the procedure I did not have the full resolution, which for me must be 1920x1080x32.

1) In the virtual machine, edit these PLIST files,

sudo pico /Extra/com.apple.boot.plist/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.Boot.plist

In this file, inside `<dict>...</dict>`, insert:

```
<key>Graphics Mode</key>
<string>1920x1080x32</string>
<key>Kernel Flags</key>
<string>"Graphics Mode"="1920x1080x32"</string>
```

sudo pico /Extra/com.chameleon.Boot.plist

In this file, inside `<dict>...</dict>`, insert:

```
<key>GraphicsEnabler</key>
<string>y</string>
<key>Graphics Mode</key>
<string>1920x1080x32</string>
<key>Kernel Flags</key>
<string>npci=0x3000 darkwake=0 "Graphics Mode"="1920x1080x32"</string>
```

I noticed that I already had some "kernel flags", so I just added another one for "Graphics Mode". Also note that "Graphics Mode" has a space inside it.

2) Shutdown the virtual machine and do the commands

```
vboxmanage setextradata "MAC OS X" "CustomVideoMode1" "1360x768x32"
vboxmanage setextradata "MAC OS X" "GUI/CustomVideoMode1" "1360x768x32
VBoxManage setextradata MountLion VBoxInternal2/EfiGopMode 3
```

After this, the virtual machine boots with full resolution.

Now, this might be overkill, and the result could be achieved perhaps with fewer options, but I tried various things until it started working.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this could be overkill. I got it working in far fewer steps: Just altered the "1920x1080x32" string to my resolution in /Extra/com.chameleon.Boot.plist and added the CustomVideo1 setting to the vbox file for the VM.

Comment: Thanks for the answer;  I altered each of the settings noted above one at a time, and it didn't work until I got to the `vboxmanage` settings.  However, I set `CustomVideoMode1` and `GUI/CustomVideoMode1` to `1920x1080x32`, and `EfiGopMode` to `5` (someone on another forum mentioned that being correct, yet undocumented, for 1920x1080).  Of course, I sub'd my own machine name in the commands.  What I didn't understand, and didn't try, were the `1360x768` values if you're going for 1920x1080.

Comment: setting EfiGopMode is the only step necessary here

Comment: Tried the same for Mavericks and did not work :(

Comment: nothing is work with me with mac os x 10.8

Comment: The new way is `VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution HxV`, as specified [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=85084#p404335) and [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#efividmode). (I can't create an answer for lack of reputation)

Answer (score 37):

```
VBoxManage setextradata "mac" "VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution" "1920x1080"
```

did the trick for me on high sierra

Comment: only this worked for me.

Comment: @TamásBarta are you working on high sierra too?

Comment: yes, from Arch Linux host

Comment: Didin't work for me on Ubuntu 17

Comment: Worked for me; High Sierra, Arch host, 2560x1080 res.

Comment: Worked for me, Arch host, Latest VirtualBox.

Comment: Was able to use `VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResoution` to set the resolution higher than any of the EfiGopMode options.  Set to `2560x1440` worked first time on XPS13 Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Worked for me, on the 2nd try. Wikipedia lists screen resolutions as 1920×1200 while the command accepts 1920x1200. `×` is not `x`, and the command expects the Latin letter "small x"! Arbitrary resolutions do not work, only (some of) the standard ones.

Comment: I was unable to change the resolution with `VBoxInternal2/EfiGopMode`. But this worked for me with `VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution`! Ubuntu 18.04 / VirtualBox 5.2.10 / macOS High Sierra (10.13.4). Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks. VBoxInternal2/EfiGopMode can't work.

Comment: This didn't work for me on High Sierra with latest VirtualBox on Windows 10 host.:(

Comment: Works great on Linux host

Comment: Works on Snow Leopard guest as well

Answer (score 19):

For the record, I found [this advice](http://eurekamoment.eu/?p=84) that allowed me to change the resolution:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "vmname" VBoxInternal2/EfiGopMode 3
```

where the last param is one of:

```
0 – 640×480
1 – 800×600
2 – 1024×768
3 – 1280×1024
4 – 1440×900
5 – 1920×1200
```

I'm running VBox 5.0.14 on OSX 10.9 (host), and the guest is OSX 10.11.

Comment: Are there higher resolutions using these numbered settings?

Comment: This works for the fixed resolutions available in the list. `1440×900` worked for me as it was same as my host resolution and i could move the guest to full screen and it was neat!

Comment: I have fedora 25 as host, and OSX sierra as guest (from vagrant box). This method worked for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: This worked for me, with doing nothing else and setting nothing else. Also, do yourselves a favor and take a snapshot before.

Answer (score 2):

I followed @winitzki and these are the steps I did.

I want to set the resolution to **1920x1080**, change yours accordingly.

***Backup files before editing.***

1. `sudo vi /Extra/com.chameleon.Boot.plist`

Add the following inside `<dict></dict>`

```
<key>Graphics Mode</key>
<string>1920x1080x32</string>
```

Update the value for `Kernel Flags` key with

```
"Graphics Mode"="1920x1080x32"
```

Final should have the following 4 lines (note some extra data in Kernel Flags, keep them as is):

```
<key>Graphics Mode</key>
<string>1920x1080x32</string>
<key>Kernel Flags</key>
<string>npci=0x3000 "Graphics Mode"="1920x1080x32"</string>
```

2. Shutdown VM.
3. Update VirtualBox config.

My VM Name is "MAC".

```
vboxmanage setextradata "MAC" CustomVideoMode1 1920x1080x32
vboxmanage setextradata "MAC" "GUI/CustomVideoMode1" 1920x1080x32
vboxmanage setextradata "MAC" VBoxInternal2/EfiGopMode 5
```

Comment: On macOS 'El Capitan' in VBox 5.1 it is enough only last 3 strings about `setextrasettings`.